# How to write a SQL query to present values horizontally

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Suppose I have one table called `Jobs`:

```
CREATE TABLE [Jobs]
(
    [JOBID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PARTDESC] [nvarchar](64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [OrderPlacedBy] [nvarchar](64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [SpecialistName] [nvarchar](64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Priority] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Symptoms] [ntext] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [CustomerNotes] [ntext] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [ShopNotes] [ntext] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobType] [nvarchar](32) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobState] [nvarchar](32) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NULL,
    [JobAddedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [JobStartedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [JobFinishedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [JobShippedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RecievedDate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

I want to see the specialist name and his jobs IDs horizontally.

```
ANA 201,502,605,701,774
BEN 102,103,051
JEN 705,401,402,509,409,408
```

A specialist may have `n` jobs. Suppose specialist `ANA` has 10 jobs where BEN has 5 jobs.

In this way I want to show specialist his jobs horizontally where the number of jobs may vary per specialist.

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: It sounds to me like that is something you should be handling at the presentation layer, not trying to force through TSQL

Comment: @Marc: There are plenty of situations where the presentation layer isn't flexible enough to handle this; you might need to put this query into a view, an Excel spreadsheet, or a reporting engine.

Answer (score 3):

Marc is right. Don't do this in SQL, do it at the presentation level.
Still, if you want to do this, take a look here:
[How to return 1 single row data from 2 different tables with dynamic contents in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124831/how-to-return-1-single-row-data-from-2-different-tables-with-dynamic-contents-in/5126137#5126137)

Applied to your situation, the code might be:

```
     select SpecialistName , LEFT(JobsIds, len(JobsIds)-1) as JobsIds from 
(SELECT j.SpecialistName ,

      ( SELECT cast(j1.JobsId as varchar(10)) + ','

           FROM Jobs j1

          WHERE j1.SpecialistName = j.SpecialistName

          ORDER BY JobId

            FOR XML PATH('') ) AS JobsIds
      FROM Jobs j
      GROUP BY SpecialistName )A;
```