# How to display multiple rows in sql server as a single row?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a SQL query to present values horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164295/how-to-write-a-sql-query-to-present-values-horizontally)

This is my query :

```
SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (
            ORDER BY tblProductPackingHdr.bmr_ID
            )AS SLNo
            ,tblProductPackingHdr.bmr_ID
            ,tblProductPackDetails.pack+' '+MAX(tblUnit.unit_Type)+' * '+CAST(SUM(tblProductPackingFinishedHdr.qty-tblProductPackingFinishedHdr.loss_Qty)AS VARCHAR) AS Pack
        FROM 
            tblProductPackingHdr
            INNER JOIN tblProductPackingFinishedHdr ON tblProductPackingHdr.product_Packing_ID=tblProductPackingFinishedHdr.product_Packing_ID
            INNER JOIN tblProductPackDetails ON tblProductPackDetails.pack_detl_ID=tblProductPackingFinishedHdr.pack_detl_ID
            INNER JOIN tblUnit ON tblUnit.unit_ID=tblProductPackDetails.unit_ID
        GROUP BY 
            tblProductPackingHdr.bmr_ID
            ,tblProductPackDetails.pack
```

And i got the output like this

```
SLNo bmr_ID        Pack
1    1         450 Ml * 100
2    2         1 Ltr * 12
3    2         350 Ml * 8
4    2         450 Ml * 19
5    27        450 Ml * 44
6    27        670 Ml * 1040
```

I want to display like this

```
SLNO   bmr_ID    Pack
----------------------
1      1         450 Ml*100
2      2         1 Ltr*12,350 Ml*8,450ml*19
3      27        450 ml*44,670 ml*1040
```

please help

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164295/how-to-write-a-sql-query-to-present-values-horizontally/5164379#5164379