# How to make 2 rows into single row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
  I have a query

   example

           Title  Description
             A      XYZ
             A      ABC

   now i want a sql query so that i can get a single row

  Output :

         Title  Description
          A      XYZ | ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @tbl table(Title nvarchar(1),[Description] nvarchar(100))
Insert into @tbl values('A','XYZ'); 
Insert into @tbl values('A','ABC'); 
Insert into @tbl values('A','PQR'); 
DECLARE @CSVList varchar(100)

SELECT @CSVList = COALESCE(@CSVList + ' | ', '') + 
   [Description]
FROM @tbl
WHERE Title='A'

SELECT @CSVList
```

Comment: This solution works well for a scalar output (@CSVList) and that does seem to be all the OP is asking for... if you need to act on a set of data see my post for one such method.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @table table (i int, a varchar(10))
insert into @table
    select 1, 'ABC' union all
    select 1, 'XYZ' union all
    select 2, '123'

select  t.i, 
        max(stuff(d.i, 1, 1, '')) [iList]
from    @table t
cross 
apply   (   select  '|' + a
            from    @table [tt]
            where   t.i = tt.i
            for xml path('')
        ) as d(i)
group
by      t.i;
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there is a group_concat function, that can help you.
Use it like this:

```
SELECT Title,GROUP_CONCAT(Description) FROM table_name GROUP BY Title
```

The output will be

```
 Title  Description
   A      XYZ,ABC
```

Then you can replace "," with "|" if you want(it can be done with replace function)

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is not a SQL server function.

Comment: I know, but when I wrote my answer question didn't have any information about sql server type.

Answer (score 0):

For 2 rows you can self join in SQL Server. This avoids the assorted "concatenate rows into a column" tricks. You can use a LEFT JOIN and NULL handling too for 1 or 2 rows

```
SELECT
   T1.Title,
   T1.Description + '|' + T2.Description
FROM
  MyTable T1
  JOIN
  MyTable T2 ON T1.Title = T2.Title

SELECT
   T1.Title,
   T1.Description + ISNULL('|' + T2.Description, '') --COALESCE for the pedants)
FROM
  MyTable T1
  LEFT JOIN
  MyTable T2 ON T1.Title = T2.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, try this: [How to return 1 single row data from 2 different tables with dynamic contents in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124831/how-to-return-1-single-row-data-from-2-different-tables-with-dynamic-contents-in/5126137#5126137)